# Assembly mov instruction suffix?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

(I am basing this question on a x86-64 architecture)

If main memory is an array of bytes indexed by addresses - how come that you should use `movq(%rdx), %rax` and not `movb(%rdx), %rax`? I mean `movq` is for moving a quad word and `movb` is for moving a byte. So with `mov#(%rdx), %rax`, the source, as I understand, is a place in memory and thus should be 1 byte. I know that the register `%rax` is in fact a quad word on x86-64 but that does not mean that we are `moving` a quad move - we are moving a byte to a place that can fit a quad word (8 bytes) - right?

So why not use `movb(%rdx), %rax` or maybe `movzbq (%rdx), %rax`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some background information. Are you programming in assembly language? Are you looking at code created by a compiler? What is the corresponding high level source code? Or what do you want to implement? Is the data a single byte or an array of bytes? What are the next instructions that use the value in `%rax`? A compiler may use other instructions than you might expect for optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suffix tells how many bytes the instruction will move.  So when you do `movq (%rdx), %rax`, 8 bytes are moved from memory starting at the address in `%rdx`.

`movb (%rdx), %rax` is not a valid instruction.  `movb (%rdx), %al` would move 1 byte from the address at `%rdx` into the bottom byte of `%rax`.  `movzbq (%rdx), %rax` moves 1 byte, zero-extends it to 8 bytes, and writes that value into `%rax`

Comment: Ahh, so when the source operand is a memory address, it does *not* mean that it will always copy 1 byte (since each address holds one byte) but that it starts from that address and read until the specified address + x bytes (in case of `movq (%someregister)`)? So with `movq (%rdx), %rax`, it would read from `(%rdx)` to `(%rdx)+8`?

Comment: From (%rdx) to (%rdx+7).

Comment: Yes, of course. I wanted to edit that in my comment but was too late. So from (%rdx) to (%rdx)+7 - is that what happens?

Comment: @Xaq: yes, wide loads/stores affect multiple bytes, and on a byte-addressable machine like x86 each of those bytes could also be addressed individually.  It would kind of defeat the purpose of having 64-bit CPUs if there was no instruction to load more than 1 byte at a time...